# mp3 @ 0x1768ac0 Header missing

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I have a school project using Opencv, a Raspberry pi 2, a Raspicam and C++. Our project needs to use a video stream from the camera to detect objects.

That's why I assume to use pipe and fifo by this line :

```
mkfifo fifo; 
raspivid -t 0 -o fifo & ./Detection fifo
```

As a result I get :

> `[mp3 @ 0x1768ac0] Header missing`

But when a well saved video is sent to the program, our project perfectly runs.

Example of good behavioured instructions :

```
raspivid -t 10000 -o video.h264 ; ./Detection video.h264
```

Do someone have an idea ?

All result I found where not suitable for our project. I maybe miss some important information.

Thank you

PS : Hope I am understandable, my english is not that good

Comment: What's the problem? Just the warning about the audio (which OpenCV doesn't handle anyway, and just discards)?

Comment: Why did you tag this question with tag [tag:c++]? I don't see any relevance. Next time using a tag, read the [tag info entry](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) to check if it's appropriate please.